# Colocar uma imagem como background no primefaces

Tags: java, css, jsf, primefaces

como faço para colocar uma imagem de background no `primefaces`. Eu já tentei algumas formas mas nenhuma deu certo. O mais perto de um resultado bom que cheguei foi usando `<p:graphicImage/>` porém quando eu minimizo um menu ou faço uma pesquisa na tabela a imagem não acompanha o resto do layout.
Veja só:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o meu template:

```
<h:body>

    <p:layout fullPage="true">

        <p:layoutUnit header="Sistema de Auditorias" position="north"
            resizable="false" closable="false" collapsible="false">
            <p:toolbar style="height:39px;">
                <f:facet name="left">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Diego Augusto"
                        style="position: relative;left: 1360px;" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Sair"
                        style="height:28px;width:90px; text-align:center;position: relative;left: 1370px;" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:toolbar>
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit header="Desenvolvido por: TI Unimed Norte Pioneiro"
            position="south" resizable="false" closable="false"
            collapsible="false">
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit header="Menu Inicial" size="200" position="west"
            resizable="false" closable="false" collapsible="false">
            <h:form>

                <p:panelMenu
                    style="background-image: url('../images/verdeBrasil.png');">
                    <p:submenu label="Arquivo">
                        <p:menuitem value="Página Principal"
                            outcome="/pages/principal.xhtml" />
                        <p:menuitem value="Sobre" />
                        <p:menuitem value="Sair" />
                    </p:submenu>

                    <p:submenu label="Auditorias">
                        <p:menuitem value="Todos Procedimentos"
                            outcome="/pages/solicitacoesGeral.xhtml" />
                    </p:submenu>
                    <p:submenu label="Relatórios"></p:submenu>

                </p:panelMenu>

            </h:form>

        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="400" header="Sobre a Auditoria"
            style="text-align:center;" resizable="false" closable="false "
            collapsible="true" effect="drop">
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="center" resizable="false" closable="false"
            collapsible="false">
            <ui:insert name="conteudo" />
            <h:panelGrid>
                <p:graphicImage styleClass="ladoDir.css"
                    style="height: 73px; width: 900px;" url="/images/verdeBrasil.png" />
            </h:panelGrid>

        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
```

Tentei fazer isso: `style="background-image: url('../images/verdeBrasil.png');"` no começo do `<p:panelMenu>` mas também não funcionou.

Comment: Não deu erro 404 quando você utilizou esse style?

Comment: Não. As vezes ele não aparece. Ou as vezes aparece bem pouquinho só algumas bordas. Acho que é porque ele fica por baixo de tudo.

Comment: já tentou colocar no form?

Comment: No exemplo de cima quando uso no panelMenu não muda nada

Comment: A imagem de cima é feita por um  <p:graphicImage>

Comment: já sim, ficou só umas brechas com a imagem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como não posso comentar pois ainda não tenho reputação, pelo que eu entendi, você deseja colocar essa imagem de fundo de toda a página, segue a solução, insira no seu **h:body**:

```
<h:body style="background: url('../images/verdeBrasil.png') repeat !important;">
```

> Observação: Um ponto importante é que qualquer inserção de **CSS** que
>   possivelmente venha sobrescrever alguma classe deste tema do
>   primefaces, deve ser incluído o **!important** ao final do seu css,
>   para assim dizer que o seu é o mais importante a ser usado.

---

Se não for a solução acima, e seu objetivo é colocar a imagem verde, somente de fundo do panelMenu, seguem três soluções:

O Primefaces, ele possui um tema próprio quando não especificamos um nosso em particular. Esse tema vem com as classes dos componentes que podem ser sobrescritas. Por isso, certas alterações não conseguem ser feitas por alteração inline. Existem algumas maneiras de fazermos isso para chegarmos a solução que você procura.

[Segundo o manual](https://speakerdeck.com/player/057b8d7962d2466f9f24cd45f559b8da?slide=351#), o component panelMenu, tem as seguintes propriedades para se alterar esteticamente:

- **.ui-panelmenu** Sobrescrevendo este item, você altera o corpo todo do componente.
- **.ui-panelmenu-header** Sobrescrevendo este item, você altera cabeçalho menu.
- **.ui-panelmenu-content** Sobrescrevendo este item, você altera rodapé do menu.
- **.ui-panelmenu .ui-menu-list** Sobrescrevendo este item, você altera a arvore de conteúdos.
- **.ui-panelmenu .ui-menuitem** Sobrescrevendo este item, você altera um menuItem da arvore.

### Adicionando CSS á página:

Na sua página, dentro da tag  adicione o seguinte código abaixo:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-panelmenu .ui-menuitem {
        background-image: url('../images/verdeBrasil.png') !important;
    }
</style>
```

### Criando um arquivo css:

Crie um arquivo chamado estilo.css dentro da sua pasta **WebContent**, inclua o seguinte código:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-panelmenu .ui-menuitem {
        background-image: url('../images/verdeBrasil.png') !important;
    }
</style>
```

Assim, dentro da sua página dentro da tag  adicione o seguinte código:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#{request.contextPath}/estilo.css"/>
```

### Criando um tema:

O primefaces, utiliza de seu próprio tema para sobrescrever atributos css utilizados, isto pode ser alterado criando um tema, e adicionando ele ao **web.xml** do seu projeto, este deve estar contido em um jar, na pasta */WEB_INF/lib/* do seu projeto ([pág 541 da documentação](https://speakerdeck.com/player/057b8d7962d2466f9f24cd45f559b8da?slide=541#)) :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>meuTema</param-value>
</context-param>
```